# Print td style in python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello i have a problem with priting div class text on console...

this is my code:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

lol = input("Click to print div class text on console...")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("<any link to verification code")

verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")))
print(verification_code)
```

But im getting this:

> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="c0ef884e-a0af-4935-8891-a763d5d7c285", element="a9285a5c-ba68-4b79-b515-249baeaddaf5")>

This is html code:

```
<td style="padding:10px;color:#565a5c;font-size:32px;font-weight:500;text-align:center;padding-bottom:25px;">629107</td>
```

so i need print 629107 code on console.

and This is full seen of html code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYbwj.png)

Question 2:

I have this code:

```
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")))
```

and i need write 629107 code on input class.

this is xpath of input class:

```
/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input
```

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the web element itself.
To get it's text you should apply `.text` on it, like this:

```
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='address']")))
print(verification_code.text)
```

Also, you should use element_visibility, not element_presence to get the element text properly. So try this:

```
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='address']")))
print(verification_code.text)
```

Comment: But from the HTML of that element I can't see how you will locate that element with `//*[@id='address']` xpath locator?

Comment: Thanks! it worked. btw i did put wrong xpath i will edit it also how i have other question u can check the question. Thanks

Comment: For the second question please ask a separate question.